# Mysql add an extra column at end instead of using a union

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two queries so the data shows up in one table.  I am using a union to combine the two queries.  However, everything is added to the same column, what do I change so the results from the different queries take up a new column.
Here is an image of the query result.[image]

Here is my code

```
select * from(

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 18 and 25 THEN 'Under 25'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN '25 - 40'
    WHEN age >= 40 THEN 'Over 40'
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Not Filled In (NULL)'
END as age_range,
COUNT(*) AS count,
 CASE
    WHEN age between 18 and 25 THEN 1
    WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN 2
    WHEN age >= 40 THEN 8
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 9
END as ordinal

FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, users.birthdate_on, CURDATE()) AS age FROM users
join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id
where users.plan <> 'domain' and users.plan <> '' and users.plan <> 'domain_cpi' and users.birthdate_on is not null 
) as derived

GROUP BY age_range


union 

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 18 and 25 THEN 'Under 25'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN '25 - 40'
    WHEN age >= 40 THEN 'Over 40'
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Not Filled In (NULL)'
END as age_range2,
COUNT(*) AS count2,
 CASE
    WHEN age between 18 and 25 THEN 1
    WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN 2
    WHEN age >= 40 THEN 8
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 9
END as ordinal

FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, users.birthdate_on, CURDATE()) AS age FROM users) as derived2

GROUP BY age_range2
) as test2




ORDER BY ordinal
```

I want the result so only one under 25 shows, but the two results for under 25 493 and 2046 are in different columns.  Same for all other ranges

Comment: So what do you want the result to look like??

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I added a comment at the end.  Let me know if I need to further explain what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to put a JOIN to derived.age_range ON test2.age_range2

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 18 and 25 THEN 'Under 25'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN '25 - 40'
    WHEN age >= 40 THEN 'Over 40'
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Not Filled In (NULL)'
END as age_range, 
CASE
    WHEN age between 18 and 25 THEN 1
    WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN 2
    WHEN age >= 40 THEN 8
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 9
    END as ordinal,
    count, count2
FROM (
    SELECT
    derived.age,
    COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM (
        SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, users.birthdate_on, CURDATE()) AS age FROM users
        join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id
        where users.plan <> 'domain' and users.plan <> '' and users.plan <> 'domain_cpi' and users.birthdate_on is not null 
        GROUP BY age
    ) as derived

    JOIN

    SELECT
    derived2.age,
    COUNT(*) AS count2
    FROM (
        SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, users.birthdate_on, CURDATE()) AS age FROM users
        GROUP BY age
    ) as derived2

    ON derived.age = derived2.age

)
ORDER BY ordinal ASC;
```

Comment: I tried a join and got the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT,
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 18 and 25 THEN 'Under 25'
    WHEN age BETWEEN' at line 28"

Comment: Ah ok, I think I know what needs to be done... but it will take time. Select only the age from each table derived,test2 and JOIN ON the age field. Perform the CASEs outside of this.

Comment: Ok I've re-written my answer. There could easily be flaws, because I refactored as quickly as I could without any means to test. Hopefully it points you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need 2 queries just a left join instead. The `count()` function ONLY increments for non-null values so you can have users counted even if they don't meet the subscription criteria.

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN age BETWEEN 18 and 25 THEN 'Under 25'
          WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN '25 - 40'
          WHEN age >= 40 THEN 'Over 40'
          WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Not Filled In (NULL)'
      END as age_range 
    , CASE
          WHEN age between 18 and 25 THEN 1
          WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN 2
          WHEN age >= 40 THEN 8
          WHEN age IS NULL THEN 9
      END as ordinal
    , COUNT(DISTINCT id)    AS user_count        # distinct might not be needed
    , COUNT(subscriber_id)  AS subscriber_count
FROM (
      SELECT
            users.id
          , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, users.birthdate_on, CURDATE()) AS age
          , subscriptions.user_id                              AS subscriber_id
      FROM users
      LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON users.id = subscriptions.user_id
            AND users.plan <> 'domain'
            AND users.plan <> ''
            AND users.plan <> 'domain_cpi'
            AND users.birthdate_on IS NOT NULL
      ) d
GROUP BY
      CASE
          WHEN age BETWEEN 18 and 25 THEN 'Under 25'
          WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN '25 - 40'
          WHEN age >= 40 THEN 'Over 40'
          WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Not Filled In (NULL)'
      END
    , CASE
          WHEN age between 18 and 25 THEN 1
          WHEN age BETWEEN 25 and 40 THEN 2
          WHEN age >= 40 THEN 8
          WHEN age IS NULL THEN 9
      END
```